# Converting aesthetic 'x' from character to list type in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, bioinformatics

The first few lines of my data look like this

```
GO.ID   Term    Annotated   Significant Expected    raw.p.value         
GO:0060012  "synaptic transmission, glycinergic"    1   1   1   1           
GO:0001666  response to hypoxia 1   1   1   1           
GO:0002009  morphogenesis of an epithelium  1   1   1   1           
GO:0001667  ameboidal-type cell migration   1   1   1   1           
GO:0031323  regulation of cellular metabolic process    19  19  19  1           
GO:1904292  regulation of ERAD pathway  1   1   1   1           
GO:0031324  negative regulation of cellular metabolic process   2   2   2   1
```

I have imported this data in R  as test. I am using a package called ggupsetR to find out common genes in the dataset. The code block I am using is

```
test +
    distinct(Annotated, Significant, Expected,raw.p.value .keep_all=TRUE) +
    ggplot(test,aes(x=GO.ID))+
    geom_bar()+
    scale_x_upset(n_intersections = 5)
The error I am getting is as follows

Error in f(..., self = self) : 
  Error in scale_upset for aesthetic 'x'. 'X must be of type list. It currently is character. Please guide me on how to get rid of this error.
```

```
#packages to be loaded include 
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggupset)
```

Comment: As the error states, `Go.ID` needs to be a list, not a character.  I don't knopw enough about your data to suggest an appropriate transformation.  But the help pages for the ``ggupset` package suggest to be that the x variable needs to classify rows into (multiple) categories, rather than simply identify them.

Answer (score 0):

Checking [CRAN documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggupset/readme/README.html) for `ggupset` helped find this out and you can confirm, but you're using binary operators `+` to link all those together.  These only work to combine `ggproto` objects in `ggplot()`.  In other words, you use them to add `ggplot()`, `geoms`, and `themes` together.

`distinct()` from the `ggupsetR` package is a method that does not create a `ggproto` object.  Therefore, you need to use the pipe operators `%>%` instead of binary operators `+`.  This should therefore work fine:

```
test %>%
    distinct(Annotated, Significant, Expected,raw.p.value .keep_all=TRUE) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=GO.ID)) +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_x_upset(n_intersections = 5)
```